# Encryption Algorithm for meaningful encrypted text

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption

Can anyone suggest me an algorithm which encrypts data. The encrypted data should not be same as original data but it should have some meaning. For example, if i encrypt "hi" it can display "what"

Comment: Today it's not encryption, it's encoding!!! :). Look at substitution ciphers, for example, Cesar (ROT-13)

Comment: Do only single words need to have a new meaning? Or shall the entire text have a new meaning

Comment: But are substitution ciphers secure?

Comment: The entire text should have a new meaning

Comment: it should work with random text data

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Could you edit your question and clarify what exactly your requirements are?

Comment: When I understood you correctly, you are trying to find a stenography technique to encode data in an auto-generated text which looks like written by a human when examined casually. Is that correct?

Comment: no no..I am trying to find a technique that auto generates texts that makes sense and replaces the original text and then can be decoded again

Comment: the text is not handwritten..it is written in a texteditor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encryption and encoding are largely orthogonal. No need to mix them. So I'd:

1. Compress input
2. Encrypt input with standard encryption
3. Write a function that encodes arbitrary binary data as a sequence of words, and hand the ciphertext to it.

The difficulty of step 3 depends on how you interpret "texts that makes sense". No matter what you do, a human will probably be able to distinguish you text from meaningful text.

In the simplest case, just take a list of say 4096 words and then split the ciphertext into 12 bit blocks, mapping each to a word. For a fancier approach, markov chains are one consideration.